# Loading certain elements from another website

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a view member screen for another website(not on my domain). I am trying to retrieve certain things from this website based on their class. For example I am trying to get the avatar of the person which has the .avatar class. I have tried:

```
$('#accountPic').load('www.theWebsite.com .avatar');
```

to try and get the image link but this does not work. IS there any way to get the content of a class from another website and display it on your own?

Comment: Look into using JSONP with the `.getJSON()` method. Without using server-side code, that's the most reliable way to get data from another site -- although it won't do what you're trying to achieve. What you want to do is called "web scraping," and you can't do it using just JavaScript (thank goodness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work via client side javascript due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Assuming the site you're trying to get the information from does not have an API for external access, a work around is to grab the HTML server-side using PHP/ASP.Net etc and then request that via AJAX.

Comment: ok, I have hoping to not use php but it looks like it is inevitable at this point.

Comment: So I have loaded the site with file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/'); now I want to search for a element with <img class="avatar" ... and get the contents of it. any idea how to do this?

Comment: @NoahHuppert You'd be looking for a "PHP HTML parser" library. I haven't used any, so I can't personally recommend any Google results. However, note that if the request is coming from your PHP server, then it's not going to have the visiting user's avatar in it. To extend my answer's analogy, the website will go "Hi, PHP_AUTOMATIC_PROCESS_18!"

Comment: @Katana314 I actually figured it out. I am going to make this a Q&A. I am using php to get the website html file, in that is the users avatar always in the same tag with the same class. I then use $dom->getElementsByTagName('item') and others like it to separate the junk and get the src. I am also doing the same with the sites rss feed for about the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The first step there would be retrieving the full HTML document of the outside site. That, on its own, could very likely run you into unsolvable problems (because of browser security restrictions).

As an example of why it's a security issue: If somebank.com were to have on the homepage "Welcome back, Jonathan T. Query! Your current balance is $4000." then other sites could retrieve that text, and send it off to who knows where.

If thewebsite.com has a developer API to retrieve information from it, you could use that. I know sharing avatars between websites is a realistic goal of the OpenID project. If not, I think your problem may be unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

If the target host provide cross origin access, you can do it:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'http://www.theWebsite.com', 
    complete: function(jqXHR) { 
        var doc = $(jqXHR.responseText); 
        var avatar = doc.find('.avatar'); 
        // ...
    } 
});
```